# Grouping multiple rows in R

Tags: mysql, r, grouping, rows

I've generated a heatmap in R for microbiome data, using the following [link](http://www.molecularecologist.com/2013/08/making-heatmaps-with-r-for-microbiome-analysis/)

My data as far as rows is concerned looks like this:

```
781
782
783
547
519
575
044
045
049
```

If I want to group 781-783, 547-575 and 044-049 as individual groups and give them separate colours using the below idea:

Assigning animals to different groups (2 random groups in this case)

```
var1 <- round(runif(n=12, min=1, max=2))
var1 <- replace (var1, which(var1 == 1), "deepskyblue")
var1 <- replace (var1, which(var1 == 2), "magenta")
cbind(row.names(data.prop), var1)
```

How do I go about it? I understand that the above code, randomly generates 2 groups, but how can I specify which rows go into which group?

Thank you,

Susheel

Comment: Can you be more clear on your question? Your data is insufficient, and overall logic (3 non-random groups vs binomial random sampling) is bit unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because rownames are of necessity character and the only good range-operator in R is ":" for numeric values: you need to coerce ranges to the desired `"0nn"` format. This is untested in the absence of a proper test case (which questioners are asked to provide):

```
#look at...
sprintf("%03i", c(781:783, 547:575, 044:049))
# then....

 data.prop[ sprintf("%03i", c( 781:783, 547:575, 044:049), 'var1'] <-
      mapply(function(clr, rng) {rep(clr, length(rng) )}, 
                    c("deepskyblue",  "magenta", "green"), 
                    list(  781:783, 547:575, 44:49)
              )
```

Comment: Thanks for that `sprintf` call.  You just taught me a new way to pad strings with `0`.

Comment: The usual ways are either `sprintf` or `formatC`. Both have their quirks. I happen to find `sprintf` easier to get working correctly but others seem to find formatC easier. Your choice.

Comment: well, in particular I was referring to the `"%i"`, but now I'm seeing that it's almost the same as `"%d"`.  Reading the help I'm having trouble deciphering the difference

Comment: In this case there might not be a difference. I was assuming (without checking the help page) that "i" was for integers and that "d" was for doubles. Turns out the page says 'f' is for floating point values. I usually need to look at the help page.